# How to configure a SSH server to use a certain public key?

Tags: ssh, security, sync

I have a dual boot Windows 7 / Ubuntu 12.04 desktop and I have installed openSSH server in both (using cygwin64 under windows). I connected from my laptop, running Ubuntu 12.04, to the Cygwin64 openSSH server, and an entry to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` was normally added. Now, I am trying to connect to Ubuntu openSSH server (same IP, domain name) and I get the error:

```
WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
```

This is of course because the 2 servers running on different OSes on the same machine have created different public keys and corresponding fingerprints. Is there any way to synchronize them (i.e. copy all the public key info from one to the other)?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the best way to get around the problem. If you configure the Ubuntu side to use a different IP address than you use in Windows you shouldn't have this problem.

If you can't do that, a more straight forward solution is to disable host key checking for that host on your laptop.

Note, doing this will prevent ssh from warning you about a man-in-the-middle attack where someone is impersonating your dual boot system on your network, but that probably has a very low chance of happening.

To disable host key checking, add the following to the top of ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config:

```
Host <HOSTNAME OR IP ADDRESS>
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

The 'StrictHostKeyCheck no' option will prevent your laptop from checking the remote host identification, and the 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' option will cause ssh to save the remote host's identification to /dev/null, meaning it won't be saved.

Answer (score 0):

The default host key file is /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key for protocol version 1, and /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key and/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key for protocol version 2.  Try copying these files from your Ubuntu system to your Cygwin system (or vice versa).

Another option is to use the HostKey configuration option in sshd_config to point to an alternative host key file that is the same on both systems.